# machines (that have) gluten spores

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "gluten spores" mean in this context?

> Predictable response... "Exactly! This just proves the manipulation of Dominion devices. In researching the machines state-wide, Miriam Loxworth of the Los Angeles Upstairs University, America's foremost Food Intuitive has determined in scientific testing that only two counties' machines showed traces of high grade **gluten spores**. Just guess which two counties those were!

> Source: Online comment

Comment: Gluten is a protein, not a fungus, so I don't know how it can be said to produce spores. Does the post which this one comments on provide any clues?

Comment: What are "Los Angeles Upstairs University" and "Food Intuitive"? The "manipulation of Dominion machines" surely relates to vote counting, so plenty of context is needed.

Comment: I get zero hits for “Los Angeles Upstairs University” and “Miriam Loxworth”. Sounds like someone making up sources to give credibility to their nonsensical claims.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post appears to be satirising amateur attempts to analyse the 2020 US Elections for fraud. As is inevitable on the Internet, at least some of the analysis is rather poor.

The gist of what the poster is saying is 'these arguments that claim to prove election fraud make no sense at all'. It would be therefore pointless to over analyse it.

Comment: Right on. The poster might be simply joking.  So let this thread sink.   Thank you guys.